# Getting started with amazon chime sdk

Tags: javascript, sdk, amazon-chime

I'm sorry if this question is unwanted, but i'm kind of stuck as where to start in amazon chime sdk installation. I followed the instructions from aws chime sdk documentation and aws chime sdk github repository.

Steps so far

- Cloned the git:amazon-chime-sdk from github, stored it in /home/admin/web/site/ direction
- ran npm run start in cd demos/browser directory.
- Opened the demos/browser/app/meeting.html, but i don't see anything working over there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's tricky and a little confusing. Once you've opened the meeting.html page (or also you can try meetingV2.html) you need to click on a green icon, at the top center of the page to enable the camera. Also, you'll need to open the same meeting.html page in another browser tab, in order to simulate more than 1 attendee.

Comment: Are there any good sources to actually implement those solutions? since I find very hard the ones you get in the demo section of the amazon-chime-sdk-js. Of course they are easy to clone and start but to implement it in your on environment is another thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same kind of issue when I started working on amazon chime. But I have successfully created a basic 1-1 video-audio meeting as a demo application in Angular 13 using amazon-chime-sdk-js

Answer (score 0):

**chime-react-library sandbox**

https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/amazon-chime-sdk-component-library-react

**In this link there is a working demo by using Amazon chime library react**

https://github.com/aws/amazon-chime-sdk-component-library-react/

1. First thing first, you can fork the code samples from the sandbox, but to use it you need an AWS account with amazon-chime services enabled.
2. Then some API/lambda functions to support your meeting call from the Front-end.
3. From the Back-end you have use amazon-chime-sdk to make those APIs.

This is the summary how can you make a meeting using amazon-chime

[@pepe-alvarez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15104639/pepe-alvarez)  I hope you already overcome the hurdle, but still if it helps then I'll be glad